# Finding full form of parenthesized acronym using regex (easy)

Tags: regex

I am trying to find full-form of acronyms that have been specified in a text using parenthesis. Here is an example -

> Aberrant DNA methylation, one of the major epigenetic alterations in cancer, has been reported to accumulate in a subset of colorectal cancer (CRC), so-called CpG island methylator phenotype (CIMP), which was known to correlate with micro satellite reduced instability (MSI)-high CRC

Here, I want to be able to form a list of short-form/full-form occurrences like -

> CRC - Colorectal Cancer
>
> CIMP - CpG island methylator phenotype
>
> MSI - microsatellite instability .....

The thing is I have been able to find all parenthesized entities using `re.findall('(\(.*?\))', s)`, but finding the corresponding full-form is proving difficult. Assuming all such full-forms are on the left of the parenthesis, I can use word boundaries to find say, the 4 words before the brackets. But to rather find the correct full-form of the acronym, I want to use the following two conditions -

- the number of words be not more than 3+|SF| where |SF| is the number of characters in the short-form (micro satellite reduced instability (MSI), here the full-form has 4 words whereas the shortform has 3 characters)
- The first word of the full-form start with the first character of the short-form (eg. **c**olorectal cancer (**c**rc))

With my current understanding of regex, I have not been able to write a regex that solves the above 2 conditions and finds all such cases in the text. Could you please give me some pointers for this ?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. If WWW was an acronym for two words: "worldwide web", how would you find the acronym in "wonderful worldwide web"?

Comment: @Laurel good point. But the thing is that in my dataset, such cases are extremely rare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said before, this may be inaccurate in some cases. You will likely need to proofread the results for accuracy.

I suggest using several regexes. Here are the steps you will need to take:

1. Get the acronyms. You're already doing this with your first regex.
2. Find how many letters in the acronym.
3. Construct and run this regex: `((?:\w+\W+){1,` (acronym length +3) `})\(` acronym `\)`. For example, `((?:\w+\W+){1,6})\(CRC\)`.
   This step gets all the words within range ("not more than 3+|SF|") of the parenthesized acronym.
4. Construct and run this regex on the words you got in group 1 in the previous step: `\b` (acronym first letter) `.*`. For example, `\bC.*` for CRC. You will want to use case insensitive matching here.
   This finds the first word that starts with the given letter within the range; you may catch extra words before the acronym this way.

---

Note that I'm using the regex definition of "words", meaning that `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is matched by `\w`, (unless you're in Unicode mode, when it matches `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`). You may want to change `\w` and `\W` (and also `\b`, if the first word can come directly after a hyphen).

Comment: why are you using `\W+` ?

Comment: @ChahatUpreti `\W` matches non-words (which may or may not be exactly what you need), but you definitely need the `+` so that a sequence like "word+period+space+word" can be parsed.